# Dask method on dataframe to return a dictionary of applied method results

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a function that creates a list of values. Here's a simplified version of what such a function might do, when given a row from a dataframe.

```
def generate_key_list_pair(row):
    some_list = do_something_to_make_a_list(row)
    return some_list
```

I would like to then apply that method to all rows in a Dask dataframe and return a dictionary such that:

```
ddf.apply(generate_key_list_pair)
```

...would return a dictionary whose keys were the row ids and whose values were the results from each rows applied function, e.g.:

```
{
    1: [3.0, 4.12, 5.2, 23.1, 4.9],
    ...
    n: [9.34, 8.12, 3.42, 12.1, 34.2]
}
```

Where `1` through `n` would be the `id` column value from the row Series object passed into each `generate_key_list_pair` function call.

Edit: 1...n could be a unique identifier that exists within a column in the original dataframe.

Comment: To be clear, 1..n are the row index values within each partition (so they repeat for each partition) ?

Comment: Thanks for asking that. 1...n could be a unique identifier that exists within a column in the dataframe. I can edit the original question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask-Dataframe methods like `apply` generally give you back more dataframes, which is not what you are after in this case. You can however access the constituent pandas dataframes and still maintain the scheduler/parallel operations:

```
def dict_from_part(df):
    d2 = df.set_index('id_column').apply(do_something_to_make_a_list, axis=1)
    # d2 is a series, so long as the number of elements of the lists
    # isn't accidentally the same as the number of columns
    return d2.to_dict()

parts = [delayed(dict_from_part)(df) for df in ddf.to_delayed()]
```

Now `parts` is a list of `delayed` objects, each of which can be `compute`-d to a dictionary like you want. If you wanted to combine these dictionaries, you would need to instead create tuples (e.g., items()) and sum these.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand that code correctly, when parts is called, it is returned a list, each element of which represents one of the partitions?. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, each element is a handle to the dictionary generated from one of the partitions of the original dataframe. The computation will not actually happen until you call compute (which is a method of each element, or you can use `dask.compute` on the whole list).